# Getting select data from two tables where session id

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have a issue with a SELECT query. I'm basically trying to get information from two different tables, I want the customer information (orders) + the customers products (orders_products) and I only want the information for that specific ID.

Both tables have the `user_id` column.

```
$conn = new PDO('mysql:host='. DB_HOST .';dbname='. DB_NAME . ';charset=utf8', DB_USER, DB_PASS);
$conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
$sth = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM orders, orders_products WHERE `orders.user_id` = `orders_products.user_id` = :user_id");
$sth->bindValue(':user_id', $_GET['id']);
$sth->execute();
$result = $sth->fetch();
```

Comment: I think you want to start look into `JOIN`. See here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/join.html Also to understand what the different joins do, this is a really good question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/5706437/3933332

Comment: Thanks worked great with help from SQLfiddle @Rizier123

Comment: Cool that you could figure it out yourself! (BTW: You can answer your own question if you want and share it with everyone (+You also can accept your own answer), you also can delete your question. But the decision is yours what you do with your question, just wanted to show you different ways/possible things you can do)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT orders.*, orders_products.* FROM orders
JOIN orders_products on orders_products.user_id = orders.user_id
WHERE `orders.user_id` = :user_id;
```

Hope this help :)